Display power point file in browser
In my web application I want to display a  power point file containing audio in browser. I have used Microsoft office online viewer for this by providing the below link
http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=[OFFICE_FILE_URL]
http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embedaspx?src=[OFFICE_FILE_URL]
I am able to display the ppt file with the above links but the issue is that the audio is not playing. My ppt file is kind of tutorial slides with button clicks and having user interactions. Any one can help me on this ? or any other alternate options to display ppt file in browser?
I have tried office online viewer, but the sound is not playing
